# Reports in Customer Portal

Tags: reporting, customer-portal

Clicking Reports tab in Customer Portal says:

> Insufficient Privileges You do not have the level of access necessary
>   to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of
>   the record or your administrator if access is necessary.

Report folder is `This folder is accessible by all users, including portal users`

User License is `High Volume Customer Portal`.

I don't want to change User License. Is there any other option?

Comment: The user obviously has access to the reports tab, but does the user have permissions to run reports?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reports are not available for High Volume Customer Portal Users.

Reports are available to the higher-level portal licenses (Customer Portal Manager Custom) and not available to the lower-level ones (Customer Portal, High Volume Customer Portal, etc.).

To see the reports tab for user licenses where reports are allowed:

- Clone the profile
- Edit the cloned profile to enable the Run Reports permission (under General User Permissions)
- Enable the Reports tab for the cloned profile
- Assign the desired portal user to that profile
- Grant portal users access to the folders on your Salesforce Reports tab that contain the reports you want them to run.
- Set the organization-wide default sharing model to Private on objects you want portal users to report on.
- Assign portal users to permission sets or profiles that include the “Run Reports” permission.

Answer (score 2):

Also make sure the user has READ access to the objects in the report.  That's bitten me more than once!